# js html script only works on one gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I made a scrollable gallery with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzXyRa7jwk4&list=PLQthIda1maZcb0ADbOVT4mRYQVHLqSxqL&index=3&t=1s&ab_channel=GreatStack
It works fine on my first gallery, however if I try to apply the script to the other two galleries, they don't scroll at all

Here is the code that works

```js
let scrollContainer= document.querySelector (".gallery")
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById("arrowLeft")
let arrowRight = document.getElementById("arrowRight")

scrollContainer.addEventListener ("wheel", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault ();
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft +=evt.deltaY;
});

arrowLeft.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  scrollContainer.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft -= 900;
});

arrowRight.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  scrollContainer.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += 900;
});
```

```html
<section id="Welcome">
  <h2>
    Welcome
  </h2>
  <div class="gallery-wrap">
    <img id="arrowLeft" src="images/arrow_left.jpg">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div>
        <span >
          <a href="https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/">
            <img src="images/audiovisualmedia.jpg">
            <p>
              Placeholder
            </p>
          </a>
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm_building.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/mobilemedia.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>
          <img src="images/audiovisualmedia.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm_building.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/mobilemedia.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="arrowRight"src="images/arrow_right.png">
  </div>            
</section>
```

As stated it works, however if I copy both the gallery and the script and give them different classes and IDs (eg. `.gallery2` instead `.gallery`) somehow it doesn't work.

```js
let scrollContainer= document.querySelector (".gallery2")
let arrowLeft2 = document.getElementById("arrowLeft2")
let arrowRight2 = document.getElementById("arrowRight2")

scrollContainer.addEventListener ("wheel", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault ();
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft +=evt.deltaY;
});

arrowLeft2.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  scrollContainer.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft -= 900;
});

arrowRight2.addEventListener ("click", () => {
  scrollContainer.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += 900;
});
```

```html
<section id="Cocktails">
  <h2>
    Cocktails
  </h2>
  <div class="gallery-wrap2">
    <img id="arrowLeft2" src="images/arrow_left.jpg">
    <div class="gallery2">
      <div>
        <span >
          <a href="https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/">
            <img src="images/audiovisualmedia.jpg">
            <p> Placeholder</p>
          </a>
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm_building.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/mobilemedia.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>
          <img src="images/audiovisualmedia.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/hdm_building.jpg">
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src="images/mobilemedia.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <img id="arrowRight2"src="images/arrow_right.png">
  </div>            
</section>
```

Any Idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I've updated the code into runnable snippets.  Can you modify these so that they clearly demonstrate the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Divs and Ps are not valid children of span and you have missing end spans too. Always run your HTML through a validator when in doubt

Comment: @Krampus scrollContainer is used in the js and grabs `.gallery` for the first gallery and _should_ grab `.gallery2` for the second gallery. But yes scrollContainer is used for both. I hope I understood you correctly

Comment: @David thank you for updating the code! I have since found a solution which in hindsight was pretty easy. I had to rename the `scrollContainer` variable for each gallery to get it to work. @Krampus made a comment about this.  I will post an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a very simple solution. I needed to rename the `scrollContainer` variable in the js for each gallery I have. So for `.gallery2` I renamed it creatively `scrollContainer2`:

```
<script>
    let scrollContainer2= document.querySelector (".gallery2")
    let arrowLeft2 = document.getElementById("arrowLeft2")
    let arrowRight2 = document.getElementById("arrowRight2")

    scrollContainer2.addEventListener ("wheel", (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault ();
        scrollContainer2.scrollLeft +=evt.deltaY;
    });

    arrowLeft2.addEventListener ("click", () => {
        scrollContainer2.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
        scrollContainer2.scrollLeft -= 900;
    });

    arrowRight2.addEventListener ("click", () => {
        scrollContainer2.style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
        scrollContainer2.scrollLeft += 900;
    });
</script>
```

All galleries now work and are scrollable